# Convert locale code to jQuery standard format

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to convert locale code using javascript ?

Example:-

> en_GB become en-GB
>
> de_DE become de
>
> etc

My system return format as the left one(from rest).
I want to have something like the right one for match jquery datepicker code format. Here https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/ui/i18n

Comment: Do you have a list of all the locales? If so, you can create an function that get `key` (the left) and return a `value` (the right).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var convertLocale = function(locale) {
  var localeComponents = locale.split('_');
  console.log(localeComponents);
  return (localeComponents.length < 2) || (localeComponents[0].toLowerCase() === localeComponents[1].toLowerCase()) ? localeComponents[0] : localeComponents[0] + '-' + localeComponents[1];
};

document.write(convertLocale('en_GB'));
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer . May I know why (localeComponents.length < 2)?

Comment: @Caal It is just a check in case if `_` is not found in the original locale id.